# Request getting aborted while uploading images over HTTPS using System.Net.WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient, image-uploading, system.net.webexception

I'm using the `WebClient` class to upload images over HTTPS to a server. My C# client code talks to a web service written in PHP. I have checked all the apache settings in php.ini.

The exception that gets thrown is as follows :

```
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(Uri address, String method, String fileName)
```

It doesn't happen always (it happens around 10% of the time).

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if helped you ?

Comment: @mybirthname Thanks for the help. I need a couple of days. I've been really busy with something else. But I will accept your answer for sure once I've tried it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you research it a little bit, you will see that the common solution to this is to set `KeepAlive` property of the Request to `false`. Another one is just to increase the timeout of the request. Be aware the `timeout` is in **milliseconds**.

Check out these questions:

- [The request was aborted: The request was canceled. No solution works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548604/the-request-was-aborted-the-request-was-canceled-no-solution-works)
- [HttpWebRequest: The request was aborted: The request was canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459241/httpwebrequest-the-request-was-aborted-the-request-was-canceled)
- [WebClient UploadFile errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634470/webclient-uploadfile-errors?rq=1)